# Image slider in Angular js is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to Angular js. I have been following an example from this link to implement image slider but it is not working as expected.

https://codepen.io/Fabiano/pen/LACzk

```
<style>
    #slides_control > div{
        height: 200px;
    }
    img{
        margin:auto;
        width: 400px;
    }
    #slides_control {
        position:absolute;
        width: 400px;
        left:50%;
        top:20px;
        margin-left:-200px;
    }
</style>
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="CarouselDemoCtrl" id="slides_control">
        <div>
            <carousel interval="myInterval">
                <slide ng-repeat="slide in slides" active="slide.active">
                    <img ng-src="{{slide.image}}">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h4>Slide {{$index+1}}</h4>
                    </div>
                </slide>
            </carousel>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.10.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
<script>
    angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap']);
    function CarouselDemoCtrl($scope){
        $scope.myInterval = 3000;
        $scope.slides = [
            {
                image: 'http://lorempixel.com/400/200/'
            },
            {
                image: 'http://lorempixel.com/400/200/food'
            },
            {
                image: 'http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports'
            },
            {
                image: 'http://lorempixel.com/400/200/people'
            }
        ];
    }
</script>
```

The images are shown in list, not in slides.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the bootstrap CSS.

Add the following style reference at the top of your HTML and the slider will work.

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">`

See it in the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hmb2mjgz/

Comment: Thanks with this , i am able to solve this a sample project, but its still not working when i try to do this in laravel , Is there something different need to be done in laravel framework?

Comment: @incr3diblenoob there is nothing to do with the Laravel with this. This should work fine regardless what happens in the Laravel. Only make sure the page is loaded correctly from the server. That's it.